# Ubuntu 22.04 keeps crashing hard

Tags: kernel, crash, sysrq

I have been having a problem for a couple of months.
Basically I have this workstation running ubuntu 22.04 at the office and it keeps crashing. On average I would say it crashes every day and a half or so.
Now when I say crash I mean mouse not moving, ssh not responding, etc.

I went throught this https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/kernel-crash-dump and set-up my system to hopefully do a crashdump when it freezes. However, after a crash I look into /var/crash and there is nothing there

```
me@mymachine:~$ ls -la /var/crash/
total 12
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Oct 27 11:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root     4096 Sep 21 15:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root whoopsie  269 Oct 27 11:48 kexec_cmd
```

The documentation on the link above is very clear on how to trigger a NULL pointer crash and test that the crashdump is done, however it does not explain if anything can/needs to be done after a normal crash in order to trigger the dump. What I mean is, is the crashdump supposed to happen automatically whenever the system crashes, or am I supossed to send some SysRq command? Normally after a crash I just hold the power-on button until the whole machine powers-off, is there something I should be doing before that?

Comment: 1. I have never noticed anything funny happening to this machine up until it just crashes. I have left Ubuntu's System Monitor open and running so that hopefully the next time it crashes it captures the processes as they were right before.
2. This machine is brand new, this has been happening since I got it.

Do you know if I need to do anything to trigger a crashdump after a crash? or should that happen automatically

Comment: I can do that, and maybe I will. My question is obviously in the hopes of avoiding that. This is not what I asked, I still don't know if I need to do anything in order to trigger a crashdump after my machine crashes.

Comment: again, this was a question about crashdump, still no info on that lol

Comment: Hmm, could you edit the title of your question to point in the direction of the kind of answer you want? As I read through the question, I finally towards the end realise (I think) that you want help getting information about the crash, is that right? I would guess that there's nothing you can do to get better information because the crashes are too sudden. If you want ideas on how you might prevent the crash, I suggest including detailed hardware information (maybe `sudo lshw -sanitize`)?